# import twilio's Authy library in nest js

Tags: node.js, typescript, twilio, nestjs, authy

we usually use below statement to use authy library in node file using js ,mostly by require statement !

```
const authy = require('authy')('API KEY');
```

I've moved my code to nest eco system and now How should i do the same using typescript ,as i also want to pass API Key to it ?
I've tried below code as well ,but still it's not working

```
import { authy } from 'authy'(API KEY)
```

suggest something !

Comment: `import authy from 'authy'; authy('API KEY')`

Comment: learn about the ESM's syntax: https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_modules.html#overview-syntax-of-ecmascript-modules

Comment: @Kapobajza not working

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue in my NestJS project when using twillio library.

Currently, I have resolved this by importing it this way:

```
import authy = require('authy');
```

If, this doesn't work for you (*for any reason e.g. TypeScript compile error*), then can you try the following import statement?

```
import * as Authy from 'authy';
```

Also, let me know which one works for you.

Comment: and how to pass API key to it ?

Comment: @Aniket Can you try calling authy('API_KEY') OR Authy('API_KEY') to get the authy instance? If this doesn't work, then can you try like this:
const authyInstance = authy.default('API_KEY');

Please let me know how it goes.